# How to get the next row in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that is something like this

```
id  |  names  |  value  
1     Vicky       43
2     Erica       23
3     Rueben      33
4     Bob         54
5     Chris       60
```

Then I set them in order according to their value. Now the table looks like this.

```
id  |  names  |  value  
5     Chris       60
4     Bob         54
1     Vicky       43
3     Rueben      33
2     Erica       23
```

Now the starting point is id 5 which has a name of Chris and a value of 60. My goal is, to get the next row which has an id of 4 and name of Bob and a value of 54.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why not just select the entire table and sort on the column you want? Then you can iterate through the rows and get whatever you want.

Comment: do you want record that have second highest value?

Comment: did I mention somewhere above that I want it?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to limit the resultset:

```
SELECT * from table
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Output:

```
| ID | NAMES | VALUE |
|----|-------|-------|
|  4 |   Bob |    54 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39c851/1).

The `LIMIT` basically works this way: the first number sets the starting point (being `0` the minimal value) and the second number the amount of items to fetch (in this case only one).

**Edit:**

A different way of understanding the question would be: Given a value for a particular field (EG: `id` field with value of `5`)... what would be the previous record? As we have the id `4` in the data we should return that one.

That could be accomplished this way:

```
SELECT * from t
WHERE id < 5
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45e32/1).

This way you can traverse the results in both orders (`ASC` and `DESC`) and also get both the next or previous (`>` or `<`) rows.

Comment: I am not trying to depend on "Limit", I am trying to depend on the id, names or the value.

Comment: As a stated above I set them in order according to their value , therefore Id can be moved from places to places. What if I set the value of the row which has an Id of 5 to lower value? Then WHERE id < 5 would not be a best option

Comment: Ok to make it more clear, I will tell you my real goal. I am listing all the comments from my database and retrieve them by orders from highest to lowest depending on the sum of their thumbs up value. By default I will retrieve 20 comments (which is in order that is set from highest to lowest depending on the sum of their thumbs up value- this I have no problem with). Then   I use ajax to get the next 20 comments once the next button is clicked. Now you see what the problem if I try to depend on Limit?

Comment: Since the rows are set from highest to lowest depending on the sum of their thumbs up value the Id are at random places.

Comment: That's true, but there is a big flaw with that. Let's say I have 22 comments on my record, for the first  fetch I will retrieve the first 20 results. Now there are only 2 comments left on my record. If I press the click button, and try to retrieve the remaining result using ajax, this will return the 2 remaining comments. But what if additional comments has been added to record? Then other comments will be posted twice as well. That's why I need to find a way to know which comment has been retrieve last and use that to retrive the next results

Comment: Hmm, I think you're talking about an infinite list being fetched by batches. So it is paginated but you also keep the already fetched records. If that is the case I see what you mean now. But the issue is a concurrency one and is inherent to depend in the order of the comments. If the comments are dynamic then any "photo" you take of the data at a given time might differ from a future photo. You have to accept the fact that if you keep previous records they will be sorted in a valid order at a previous time and not a present time

Answer (score 2):

If your current ID is for example 4 then

**Next:**

select * from foo where id = (select min(id) from foo where id > 4)

**previous:**

select * from foo where id = (select max(id) from foo where id < 4)

Answer (score 1):

sql server:

```
with temp as
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value desc) AS ROWID, * FROM table_name 
)
SELECT * from temp where ROWID=2
```

mysql:

```
SELECT * from table
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that this is a PHP related question?

If that's so, then you can use PHP's mysql or mysqli_fetch functions to get what you want... along with a loop

This is your basic loop-through-a-mysql-query

```
$sql  =  mysql_query( "SELECT * from table ORDER BY value DESC" );
while ( $r = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) ) {
  echo $r['value'] . "<br />\n";
}
```

If you want to have them all at your disposal and be able to call either one of them at will, you will need to store the data in an accessible array, like so

```
$sql  =  mysql_query( "SELECT * from table ORDER BY value DESC" );
$theData = array();
while ( $r = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) ) {
  $theData[] = $r['value'];
}
```

Then, to access the SECOND value, use this

```
echo $theData[1];
```