# Multiple selects in one query, based on previous query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e4fb/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EcomGroupProductRelation
(
    GroupProductRelationProductID varchar(255), 
    GroupProductRelationSorting int
);

INSERT INTO EcomGroupProductRelation
(   GroupProductRelationProductID, 
    GroupProductRelationSorting
)
VALUES
    ('OneProd', 4),
    ('Another', 3),
    ('OneMore', 2),
    ('LastProd', 1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
  SELECT 
    GroupProductRelationSorting
  FROM 
    EcomGroupProductRelation
  WHERE
    GroupProductRelationProductID = 'Another' /* returns 3*/
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e4fb/1/0)**:

```
| GROUPPRODUCTRELATIONSORTING |
|-----------------------------|
|                           3 |
```

**QUESTION:**
- How can I select the next row - based on `GroupProductRelationSorting`, in the same query?

The result I would like to output, should be:

```
| GROUPPRODUCTRELATIONPRODUCTID | GROUPPRODUCTRELATIONSORTING |
|-------------------------------|-----------------------------|
|                       OneProd |                           4 |
```

I know I can do something like this (pseudocode-ish):

```
 WITH Temp AS
 (
      SELECT 
           GroupProductRelationSorting
      FROM 
           EcomGroupProductRelation
      WHERE
           GroupProductRelationProductID = 'Another' /* returns 3*/
 )

 SELECT 
      * 
 FROM 
      EcomGroupProductRelation
 WHERE 
      GroupProductRelationSorting=Temp+1
```

[(Based on the answer found here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342502/680223)

But I can't seem to get my head around how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT
      GroupProductRelationSorting,
      GroupProductRelationProductID,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GroupProductRelationSorting) rw
   FROM EcomGroupProductRelation
)

SELECT
  c2.*
FROM cte c1
JOIN cte c2 ON c1.rw = c2.rw-1
WHERE c1.GroupProductRelationProductID = 'Another'
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e4fb/5/0

Answer (score 0):

You almost wrote the answer.
You just need to change a bit your code

From this :

```
  SELECT * FROM EcomGroupProductRelation WHERE GroupProductRelationSorting=Temp+1
```

To this

```
 SELECT * FROM EcomGroupProductRelation WHERE GroupProductRelationSorting=(SELECT GroupProductRelationSorting FROM Temp)+ 1
```

You was giving table, but you need to give scalar value.

Or you can put first select value to variable and then filter it:

```
DECLARE @Temp INT = 0

SELECT @Temp = GroupProductRelationSorting
FROM EcomGroupProductRelation
WHERE GroupProductRelationProductID = 'Another' /* returns 3*/

 SELECT * FROM EcomGroupProductRelation WHERE GroupProductRelationSorting=@Temp+1
```

Comment: Great! First answer works. I can't get the second to work..
But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @EcomGroupProductRelation TABLE 
(
    GroupProductRelationProductID varchar(255), 
    GroupProductRelationSorting int
);

INSERT INTO @EcomGroupProductRelation
(   GroupProductRelationProductID, 
    GroupProductRelationSorting
)
VALUES
    ('OneProd', 4),
    ('Another', 3),
    ('OneMore', 2),
    ('LastProd', 1);

 SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 *
        FROM   @EcomGroupProductRelation
        WHERE  GroupProductRelationSorting >= 3
        ORDER  BY GroupProductRelationSorting) T
ORDER  BY GroupProductRelationProductID DESC
```

OR

```
 ;WITH Temp AS
 (
      SELECT GroupProductRelationProductID,
           ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY GroupProductRelationSorting )AS Rn
      FROM 
           @EcomGroupProductRelation

 )
 SELECT P.GroupProductRelationProductID 
 FROM Temp P
 LEFT JOIN Temp T ON P.RN = T.Rn + 1
 WHERE T.GroupProductRelationProductID = 'Another'
```

Comment: This works, if i strip all `@` . Why are they there? :) Thanks

Comment: i just used table variable @table to get rid of creating objects or temp tables in my database..

Comment: Okay, that gives sense :) Thank you